# Wiper motor going slow on high speed

Tags: electrical, windshield-wipers

I've got this 2 wiper motor for a personal project. I need both to work at the same speed, but this is my first time in manipulate them. I'v only opened one of those motors because i had to isolate them, but i think that i've messed up, like:

- Trying to pull the gear with brute force (when i have to unscrew a nut and pull off the lever)
- Cutting the ground brush
- Using the low and high speed to move the motor directly to a 12V 30A power supply
- Yesterday i've put some grease on the gear

And this are the symptoms:

- Vibration
- Heat
- Friction
- Weird sound when I put it on a different position

Also i've tested the resistance with at multimeter at 2000 ohms and i've got a higher value on that motor compared with the other one, so on my point of view there's something making resistance

I'll leave a video. The motor with troubles is on the top
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTiuGSyDNuw